# creating RDF triple and RDF store using jena from xml file

Tags: java, xml, rdf, semantic-web, jena

I use the following java program to extract information from an xml file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 

public class ExtractInfo {

public static void main(String argv []) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        File file = new File("page.xml");
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);

        // normalize text representation
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + 
            doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
        int totalPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();
        System.out.println("Total no of people : " + totalPersons);

        for (int s=0; s<listOfPersons.getLength(); s++) {
            Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
            if (firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element firstPersonElement = (Element)firstPersonNode;
                //-------
                NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("first");
                Element firstNameElement = (Element)firstNameList.item(0);

                NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("First Name : " + 
                       ((Node)textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                //-------
                NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("last");
                Element lastNameElement = (Element)lastNameList.item(0);

                NodeList textLNList = lastNameElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("Last Name : " + 
                       ((Node)textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                //----
                NodeList ageList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("age");
                Element ageElement = (Element)ageList.item(0);

                NodeList textAgeList = ageElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("Age : " + 
                    ((Node)textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
            }
        }
    } catch (SAXParseException err) {
        System.out.println ("** Parsing error" + ", line " 
            + err.getLineNumber () + ", uri " + err.getSystemId());
        System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage());
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Exception x = e.getException ();
        ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Could some one please help me in generating RDF triples from the extracted information and **create a triple store using Jena** containing all the triples. I am quite new to RDF, and Jena, So I do need your help guys ,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Resource resource=OntModel.createResourc(NameSpace+"Doutorado_em_Engenharia_de_Sistemas_e_Computacao");
Property prop=OntModel.createProperty(http://www.owl-ontologies.com/OntologyBase.owl#program_Provided_By);
Resource obj=OntModel.createResource(NameSpace+"Universidade_X");
OntMode.add(resource,prop,obj);
```

Before applying it, you should first create an instance of OntModel for your ontology.

[http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/11084/add-triples-in-an-ontology-using-jena-api](https://web.archive.org/web/20141115033015/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/11084/add-triples-in-an-ontology-using-jena-api)